# String pattern which starts with # @ and can contain underscore and minus

Tags: java, regex, string

I try to make a string pattern that can contain UTF-8 characters (öäå, etc) and match the following criteria in Java (1.7);

- Must start with # or @
- Must be lower-case
- Can contain - or _ (minus and underscore), no other special char
- Can contain digits (0-9)
- Min 3 and maximum 15 characters long

What I have at the moment that works but are missing many of the criteria.

> "#\p{javaLowerCase}+"

I don't know how to complete and add the rest of the criteria. How would a **regex** expression look like that can accommodate the criteria I have?

Comment: `Min 3 and maximum 15 characters long` including `#` or `@` or after them?

Comment: `"^[#@][-_a-z0-9]{3,15}$"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This translates into a regex in a relatively simple way:

```
"[#@][\\p{javaLowerCase}\\d_-]{2,14}"
```

This translates the "Min 3 and maximum 15 characters" inclusive of the `#` or `@` at the beginning. If these should not be counted, change the suffix to `{3,15}`.

Comment: @Pshemo You're right, I missed that part initially. This should now be fixed. Thanks!

Comment: Thank @Pshemo, that did the work. It will exclude the # and @, so I'll use the {3,15}.

Comment: If I would except some more special char, can I add them to the criteria \\d_-. Like "..\\d_-!&]..." for adding ! and & ?

Comment: @Chris When you add more characters, make sure that the dash `-` is at the end.